# Reorder each row from end to beginning in R

Tags: r

I need help in rearranging my data set from right to left in R.
This is the original dataset:

Sorry for the confusion, but they are not string. It is a dataset like:

```
Column_a, Column_b, Column_c, Column_d, Column_e, Column_f, Column_g

A           A          B         B          C

A           B          A         C

A           C          B         A          C        B          B
```

Using rev function, i get this:

Column_a, Column_b, Column_c, Column_d, Column_e, Column_f, Column_g

```
                   C         B          B       A          A

                             C          A       B          A
```

B           B          C         A          B       C          A

But how to get rid of those blank/NA cells?

The Ideal output looks like this:

Column_a, Column_b, Column_c, Column_d, Column_e, Column_f, Column_g

C         B          B       A          A

C         A          B       A

B         B          C       A          B       C          A

Thanks!

Comment: Check out `stri_reverse` in the [`stringi`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/index.html) package.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. They are not string, but a data set. Each letter is in a separate cell. So AABBC is one observation with five columns. Thanks.